# Properties of hidden layers in neural network

Tags: neural-networks

I'm wondering if columns in the hidden layers can be forced to be orthogonal in a simple MLP.

A simple example :
Let's say my input and output are :  $X$ shape $(10,3)$ 
and  $Y$ shape $(10,1)$.

With two weight matrix : $W_1$ shape $(3,2)$ and $W_2$ shape $(2,1)$

Lets define $V$ as  $V = XW_1$ shape $(10,2)$

Is there a way to force both columns of $V$ to be orthogonal by adding a constraint ? How can this be done mathematically speaking in a neural network ?

```
V[:,0].dot(V[:,1].T) = 0
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example the simplest solution is to factorize the inputs. Consider the orthgonality condition of yours:
$$V'V=I$$
$$(XW_1)'XW_1=$$
$$W_1'X'XW_1=I$$
$$W_1W_1'X'XW_1W_1'=WW_1'$$
$$W_1W_1'X'X=I$$
$$W_1W_1'=(X'X)^{-1}$$

So, all you need to do in this case is to factorize the inverse of the covariance matrix $(X'X)^{-1}$ of inputs. This can be done with [Cholesky decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cholesky_decomposition), for instance.

So, if you have NN and want to do this to a layer other than the first, then you'd have to plug this procedure manually, maybe implement your own layer. I don't think you could do this with out of the box layers in popular frameworks.

A less elegant solution would be to impose this condition in the cost function. So, you'd store the $V$ matrix in cache, then when you calculate the cost function use its deviation from orthogonality as a component of the cost.

Comment: Very interesting answer, thank you. I'm gonna try the first method then the second one if I feel like it. Im not using a library to create my NN so I can implement it.